# When set custom header , why the script tag request throw cross origin error in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, web

In puppeteer set custom header:

```
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'X-ENV': 'test'
})
```

Open a Page in Puppeteer, the tidy html code below:

```
<body>
    <script src="xxxxx/static/js/main.87874446.chunk.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
</body>
```

and the puppeteer will throw error:

```
Access to script at 'xxxxx/static/js/main.87874446.chunk.js' from origin 'xxxxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

why the script tag resource need set the cors?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding the script tag programmatically somewhere you can do something like,

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
 const whiteList =['document','script','xhr','fetch'];
if(!whiteList.includes(req.resourceType)){
return req.abort();
}
req.continue()
});
```